# How do I map json data to get all the individual components?

Tags: json, reactjs, laravel

I want to get all the individual components from this data that I'm getting from my API. But the data that comes from the API is like this:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Burger",
      "price":8.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Poutine",
      "price":9.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

If I use the map function on this array, it says the map function does not exist. And there is no common array name I can use that will get me all the data. Should I use a for loop to run through all the individual products in this?

Comment: Looks like an object literal with numbers as keys, which is definitely not an array. Possibly the JSON transformation in your Laravel backend that's doing this instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an object, but it looks like the properties "keys" are all ordinal numeric numbers.

If you don't care about the keys, you can just call `Object.values()` on it to return an array of the values, upon which the map function will work.

```
var obj ={  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Burger",
      "price":8.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Poutine",
      "price":9.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   }
}; 

var justTheValues = Object.values(obj); 

//get the list of just the ids 
var idList = justTheValues.map(function(item){  
   return item.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please `Object.entries(data).map(item => item[1]).map()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map of lodash

```
 import _ from 'lodash'
    let data ={  
       "1":{  
          "id":1,
          "name":"Burger",
          "price":8.99,
          "quantity":"2",
          "attributes":[  

          ],
          "conditions":[  

          ]
       },
       "2":{  
          "id":2,
          "name":"Poutine",
          "price":9.99,
          "quantity":"2",
          "attributes":[  

          ],
          "conditions":[  

          ]
       }
    }; 

    _.map(data,( item) => console.log(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component, map through values with for in loop to generate array of components.

```
let arr = [];
        for(let i in obj){
          let item = obj[i]
          arr.push(<DataComp {...item}/>)
        }
```

Here you have a working snippet so you can check it out.

```js
class DataComp extends React.Component {
  render(){
    //here you can setup your child component however you need
    return (<div>Name: {this.props.name}, Price: {this.props.price}</div>); 
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let obj = {  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Burger",
      "price":8.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Poutine",
      "price":9.99,
      "quantity":"2",
      "attributes":[  

      ],
      "conditions":[  

      ]
   }
};
  let arr = [];
    for(let i in obj){
      let item = obj[i]
      arr.push(<DataComp {...item}/>)
    }
    return (<div>{arr}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```